# emacs warning Lisp directory does not exist

Tags: emacs

Whenever I start my emacs, I get warning like:

```
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp' does not exist.
```

I upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04.

Please help me remove this warning.

Comment: Have you tried reinstall emacs?

Comment: yes I tried, but no luck

Comment: worked..installed everything related to emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Synaptic Package manager
2. Search for emacs
3. Reinstall all packages having emacs in it.